# :contains case sensitive not working appropriately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added the code to overwrite the contains method however I am still not getting the right result. I have created a JFiddle to show the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/zjAyX/   I have also tried the code that works with the jQuery 1.8 which is the version of jQuery I'm using. Where do I place the code?

```
$(function() { 

    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "containsIN": function(elem, i, match, array) {
    return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
    });

$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {

    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("tbody").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.hide();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();



    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {

        var $t = $(this);

        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});

});
```

Comment: It works fine in the fiddle you linked...

Comment: the fiddle is working fine... it is changing the color of jQuery, Javascript and JQUERY

Comment: change `f ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {` to `f ($t.is(":containsIN('" + data[d] + "')")) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:containsIN()` instead of `contains()` in your condition.

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        if ($t.is(":containsIN('" + data[d] + "')")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85WJ8/)